# How to use i18next without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, i18next

With i18next.js Trasnslation is working perfectly with jquery, i want use it with plain Javascript,

here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Multi Language</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topcoat/0.8.0/css/topcoat-mobile-light.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/i18next/1.6.3/i18next-1.6.3.js"></script>
    <script>
      i18n.init({lng: "en"}, function(err, t) {
        setLan(t);
      });
      function changeLang() {
        var e = document.getElementById("selLn");
        var lng = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log(lng);
        i18n.setLng(lng, function(err, t) {
          setLan(t);
        });
        $('#lbl').html("loaded Language package : /locales/" + lng + "/translation.json");
      }
      function setLan(t) {

        $(".nav").i18n();
        $(".content").i18n();
        var appName = t("app.name");
        console.log(navigator.language);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body >

    <div class="topcoat-navigation-bar">
      <div class="topcoat-navigation-bar__item center full">
        <h1 class="topcoat-navigation-bar__title">Multi Language Demo</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    Select Language
    <select id="selLn" onchange="changeLang()" class="topcoat-select">
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="fr">French</option>
      <option value="sp">Spanish</option>
      <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
      <option value="hi">Hindi</option>
      <option value="ml">Malayalam</option>
      <option value="ka">Kannada</option>
    </select>
    <div class="topcoat-list">
      <ul class="nav topcoat-list__container" >
        <li class="topcoat-list__item"><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.home"></a></li>
        <li class="topcoat-list__item"><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.products"></a></li>
        <li class="topcoat-list__item"><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.services"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 data-i18n="content.welcome"></h1>
    </div>

    <label id="lbl" style="font-style: italic;
           padding-left: 12px;"></label>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Translation file for French** *locales/fr/translation.js*

```
{
  "app": {
    "name": "i18next"
  },
  "nav": {
    "home": "domicile",
    "products": "produits",
    "services": "services"
  },
  "content":{
      "welcome":"De rien"
  }
}
```

I tried to replace
  `$(".nav").i18n();` with `document.querySelector(".nav").i18n();`
and removed  `<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

but it is not working

My question : 
**is i18next a Jquery dependant library?**
**Can i not use it without jquery?** 
because i saw only Jquery sample code in their site. hope someone can answer

Comment: No, i18next does not depend on jQuery. To use it without jQuery, read the documentation. http://i18next.com/pages/doc_features.html

Comment: @Jordan can u suggest what modification i need to do for the above example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you want to work with DOM elements, it's  jQuery dependent, you can use it with jQuery (and Zepto) only. However, when you just want to translate single strings, you can use it without jQuery.

Comment: that's not fully true. You can still get a translated string and replace it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used i18next, but according to the docs, you could try:

```
var x = i18n.t("key");
document.querySelector(".nav").innerHTML = x;
```

If you want to use the data attr, you probably will need just to write simple wrappers to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to stick to JQuery and naturally `$(".blabla").i18n();`, instead I used;

```
var i18nList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-i18n]');
            i18nList.forEach(function(v){
                v.text = window.i18next.t(v.dataset.i18n);
            })
```

it's picking out all DOM elements which has "**data-i18n**" attribute on html
and replacing the text through the value of that attribute which is also key for i18next JSON file.

There can be just one problem with this code, "querySelectorAll" is not supported by really really older browsers. You can check it [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

But the code will be more faster on modern browsers.